# Neural Network for classification using Keras' Functional API: One-hot-encoded y_train; Incompatible shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm using Keras' functional API to build a simple sequential neural net. Here's the shape of X_train and y_train_encoded (one-hot-encoded y_train with 10 classes).

```
X_train.shape

(60000, 28, 28)
```

```
y_train_encoded

(60000, 10)
```

I specify the architecture, compile it, and train it as follows:

```
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(28,28))
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(input)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(hidden1)
hidden3 = keras.layers.Dense(28, activation="relu")(hidden2)
output = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(hidden3)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=["accuracy"])

history=model.fit(X_train, y_train_encoded, epochs=20, validation_split=0.2)
```

I'm getting the ValueError below.

```
ValueError: Shapes (32, 10) and (32, 28, 10) are incompatible
```

I was wondering if you guys could point out where I'm going wrong. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Flatten()` layer:

```
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(28,28))
flatten = keras.layers.Flatten()(input)
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(flatten)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(hidden1)
hidden3 = keras.layers.Dense(28, activation="relu")(hidden2)
output = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(hidden3)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
```